# Google Chrome grey screen problem

Tags: google-chrome, joomla, cross-browser

Iam a web-developer and recently i have completed and launched a website (im using a CMS joomla for this website with php) and it is working fine in firefox and IE but when iam trying to view it in Chrome it is having a strange problem
for the first two seconds the contents of the website are visible but after that the whole website is greying out and iam not able to view anything on the website. This is happening for the first and even i tried to find the solution on the forums but to no avail......any help will be much appreciated.

Note : I have implemented a video on the home page of the website only that video box and the video playing inside that box is viewable but rest of the page is complete grey.

Comment: what version on chrome do you have? can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: Which addons do you use? Adblock / Flashblock caused some problems for me the last week.

Comment: @ moose im not using any of these addons

Comment: Works fine for me with Chrome 10.0.648.45 on Mac.

Comment: @ abraham im still not able to identify what is the root cause of this issue....and if at all it is working fine in chrome 10, then it should also be compatible with chrome 9....

Comment: @chris, abraham, moose thankyou all for trying to help..the problem is solved now, i debugged the code and found out that there was a image in the footer which was creating this problem after i removed that image everything is working fine and perfect now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chris, abraham, moose thankyou all for trying to help..the problem is solved now, i debugged the code and found out that there was a image in the footer which was creating this problem after i removed that image everything is working fine and perfect now